# Display error from an associatd object Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really don't know the way to display error on a view when we post datas which are associated from another model.

My needs :

I have a form displayed in `app/view/libraries/show.html.erb`

The comments are associated to library in my app. Means that for a library we can have one or many comments.

In `model/comment.rb` i put that :

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

in `app/view/libraries/show.html.erb` : i need to display error but don't know the way to retrieve it :

```
<% if @library.comment.errors.any? %>
<%= @library.comment.errors.count %>
<% end %>
```

CommentsController

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def new 
  end 

  def create 
    @library= Library.find(params[:library_id]) 
    @comment = @library.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :commenter))
    redirect_to @library 
  end 
end
```

This does not work someone can please explain to me the way it works ?? I am doing the guide rails getting start but want to add some features simple in it...

Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: How is your controller setup?

Comment: @Vimsha

`class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  
  def new
    
  end
  
  
  def create
    @library= Library.find(params[:library_id])
      @comment = @library.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :commenter))
        redirect_to @library
      
    
  end
  
end `

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the count, you can put it in flash

```
  def create 
    @library= Library.find(params[:library_id]) 
    @comment = @library.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :commenter))
    flash[:error_count] = @comment.errors.count
    flash.keep[:error_count]
    redirect_to @library 
  end 


 <% if flash[:error_count] > 0 %>
   <%= flash[:error_count] %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: I have done that but the problem is that the error must be displayed in the app/view/libraries/show.html.erb !!

Comment: It works for count but how to display errors encountered in the controller ??

Comment: If you want to show the error, put the actual error message in the flash. `flash[:error] = @comment.errors.full_messages`